# Extract part of string using wildcard - alternative solution

Tags: bash

I'm new to Bash and trying to extract a part of a string. The string is from command output. See example:

```
tmp=$(ls /sys/class/net)
echo $tmp
ens32 lo
```

This is my solution to grab the non-local interface name:

```
var=${tmp%lo*}
echo $var
ens32
```

I don't think this is the most robust solution, is there a *better* way using Bash?

GNU Bash version 4.4.7

Comment: Is this XY problem? Are you trying to list all interfaces expect loopback, why not just use some bash extended regex? `cd /sys/class/net; echo !(lo)` The `${tmp%lo*}` will remove everything after the string `lo`, better use smth like `echo "$tmp" | grep -xv lo`

Comment: `a=(/sys/class/net/!(lo)); echo "${a##*/}"` ?

Comment: Assuming you would want the interface that has the default route, you could do `ip route list | awk '/^default/{print $5}'`